# Why CRMs have two views - one for companies and one for contacts?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, design-patterns

Why are these two structure are separated?

Why not one search only that opens the profile page when you click on a user, and one that opens the company page when you click on the company?

Or one company profile like a SPA, where you can select which user you need information of?

Are these CRMs designed in this way because of user experience or software engineering (to avoid things getting messy)?

Hubspot for example:

**1- Contact Search**

[image]

**2- User profile screen**
Shown after clicking on user contact search results

[image]

**3- Company Search**

[image]

**4- The company profile screen is shown after clicking on a company from the results page**
Shown after clicking on company contact search results

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work as UX Designer in a team which the primary product is a CRM. We also do it separately. And are in a process to change it :)

Contact and Company are two different concepts for CRM and users often register them separately. But there is no reason the search should be limited. In our case we are going to implement something like this:

- The user search for a contact, we list the contact name and the company the contact works for.
- The user search for a company, we list the companies and a link to list of contacts.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, but I wonder if that has an engineering concern.

Comment: I think It really depends on what technologies you are using and how you implement it. But I don't know enough to give you a good technical answer :(